# OpenJDK 18 is installed, but BuildTools thinks its Java 11?

Tags: linux, java, fedora, minecraft, openjdk

I'm trying to run Minecraft Spigot BuildTools.jar on Fedora 35, but it says I only have Java 11 installed. The runtime environment version is 18. What am I doing wrong here, or is this a bug?

```
[banana@fedora BuildTools]$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.14.1" 2022-02-08
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.14.1+1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.14.1+1, mixed mode, sharing)

[banana@fedora BuildTools]$ java -jar BuildTools.jar
Loading BuildTools version: git-BuildTools-1fbeb7f-147 (#147)
Java Version: Java 11
Current Path: /home/banana/Downloads/BuildTools/.
git version 2.35.1
BuildTools
unconfigured@null.spigotmc.org
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djdk.net.URLClassPath.disableClassPathURLCheck=true
openjdk version "11.0.14.1" 2022-02-08
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.14.1+1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.14.1+1, mixed mode, sharing)
Attempting to build version: 'latest' use --rev <version> to override
Found version
{
    "name": "3479",
    "description": "Jenkins build 3479",
    "refs": {
        "BuildData": "641cb0c939c7c2a3c4b42f2fd7bca7c8b34254ae",
        "Bukkit": "fc460d1bb8d5f2bc9ff07dad1b7b402eed06d7c4",
        "CraftBukkit": "911bde181f16127a3904455509d318447a0f5198",
        "Spigot": "42b61526f13ff472e32714d8e7b75fce31cf1151"
    },
    "toolsVersion": 138,
    "javaVersions": [61, 62]
}

*** The version you have requested to build requires Java versions between [Java 17, Java 18], but you are using Java 11
*** Please rerun BuildTools using an appropriate Java version. For obvious reasons outdated MC versions do not support Java versions that did not exist at their release.
```

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried? Many Java specific apps allows you to specify the version of Java they'll use, and you can run more than one version of Java at a time. So, please show us what you've tried.

Comment: @music2myear My research goes as far as knowing that OpenJDK is not released by Oracle (who basically proprietized Java past 8), and I have version 18. I’ve also tried an already compiled version of spigot, which had a different error, but also seemed to indicate my version was out of date. (Something about being class 60 but only supporting class 55, will double check).

Comment: Your java "runtime" version might be 18, but your actual java **language** version is clearly 11. You probably need to install 18. https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-java-18-on-centos-fedora/

Comment: @Mokubai …okay, so Java has two versions. I suppose OpenJDK would have it’s own version, but did it have to line up perfectly 11 and 18 when there actually is an OpenJDK 11 on the Fedora PM? I’ll install that thing you suggest. Meanwhile, I wonder what I would get if I actually installed the OpenJDK 11 package. *sigh* whatever. Thanks for your help

Comment: Okay, now it's only working if i specify /opt/jdk-18/bin/java. I've uninstalled the other java I thought. I must have another java version installed. So, how to search on Fedora for installed java packages...

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your $PATH to include the jdk18 location.

In your .bashrc, add the following line:

```
export $PATH=$PATH;/opt/jdk-18/bin/
```

Logout then back in to reload your $PATH.

Here's a full installation process so it all works smoothly. Just be sure to remove any conflicting version of Java on your system. - https://linuxman.co/linux-desktop/install-java-17-in-ubuntu-debian-and-fedora/

Comment: I am sure I do have a conflicting Java version. How can I remove it, or search for what packages are installed on my system? I am familiar with the aptitude package manager interface. Is there a Fedora equivalent that will show the Java packages I have installed?

Comment: use `rpm` and `dnf`. How did you install Java in the first place?

Comment: I installed openJDK with dnf I think. I’ll have to check how to search for installed packages. Possibly, I can even tell where the conflict in Java version is from the path variable. I’ll have to do that a bit later, as I don’t have access to the system right now.